# What will happen if I use the same name for submit button which I used for form elements as an array in PHP?

Tags: php

I have used `name="question[]"` for multiple select box and the same name used for submit button name as `name="question[]"`

How can I get the values of the select box without the submit button?

Comment: 1. Change the name, 2. If your submit button is the last element, you can assume it'll be the last in the array, so you could use `array_pop()` to pop it off the array

Comment: Why are they the same name in the first place?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? What have you tried?

Comment: @billyonecan The emphasis being on *assume*, since browsers are not required to do that.

Comment: @phant0m Correct. And if you press enter, the form might be submitted without the use of the submit button, so it's value is not necessarily present at all.

Comment: I think there's only one good solution, and that is: give different elements different names.

Comment: @phant0m indeed. There is nothing that guarantees that the order of elements will be the same when posted, but I've never seen a case where they haven't

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of your submit button... it shouldn't be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to fix the name clash.

If the `value` of the `submit` button can never be one of the `select` values, you can ignore any element of `$_POST['question']` that has that value.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a jQuery/Sizzle variant on the front

```
$('select[name="question[]"]').val();
```

Will return the selected value from the select box by that name. You can then populate some other field with that value before submitting to the server.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this goes against the specification?

Comment: It doesn't, so I've amended the answer, thanks for raising it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get both the elements value as follows,

You can then access it using the following:

```
$_POST['question'][0]; 
$_POST['question'][1];
```

You can get the values of select box and submit button now.